# Hive Oozie Error Handling

Tags: hadoop, error-handling, hive, bigdata, oozie

Does anyone have any suggestion on what is the best practice around Oozie Exception/Error handling?
We have Hive Actions within Oozie workflows and find that the errors are not logging with enough detail. We need more of stack trace and more context around each failure.
Any suggestions?

Thanx in advance...

Himanshu

Answer (score 0):

Once the oozie job submitted the Yarn will responsible for the action to completes the mapreduce. Check the log in **mapred historyserver** once the job is submitted to the yarn or check it via the **job logs located in oozie** with the list of error code in **web UI**.

Answer (score 0):

The logging level of the Hive action can set in the Hive action configuration using the property `oozie.hive.log.level` . The default value is `INFO` .

You can change it to `DEBUG` and include in your Hive action configuration of your `workflow.xml`.

```
<configuration>
      <property>
                <name>oozie.log.hive.level</name>
                <value>DEBUG</value>
      </property>
</configuration>
```

This log level is in-turn passed onto `log4j` I believe.

https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/sharelib/hive/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/HiveMain.java

Comment: Good switch, I have tested it and it works. Debugging mapred hive action can be cheaty though, better drink from the source with a `yarn logs -applicationId <APP_ID>`. Thanks,